Is it Possible to Customize and Create Custom Effects in Flutter Flame (Through Inheritance, etc.)?
Is it possible to customize (e.g., through inheritance) and create custom effects in Flutter Flame? For example, in Siv3D, you can create a custom effect like a circle appearing at a clicked location and then disappearing. Can similar custom effects be created in Flame as well? (Note: I'm interested in creating custom effects, not specifically a circle effect).
Reference to custom effect in Siv3D: https://siv3d.github.io/ja-jp/tutorial3/effect/
Siv3D(C++):
Note: This is just one of many other samples.

# include <Siv3D.hpp>

struct RingEffect : IEffect
{
  Vec2 m_pos;

  ColorF m_color;

  // このコンストラクタ引数が、Effect::add<RingEffect>() の引数になる
  explicit RingEffect(const Vec2& pos)
      : m_pos{ pos }
      , m_color{ RandomColorF() } {}

  bool update(double t) override
  {
      // 時間に応じて大きくなる輪を描く
      Circle{ m_pos, (t * 100) }.drawFrame(4, m_color);

      // 1 秒未満なら継続する
      return (t < 1.0);
  }
};

void Main()
{
  Effect effect;

  while (System::Update())
  {
      ClearPrint();

      // アクティブなエフェクトの数
      Print << U"Active effects: {}"_fmt(effect.num_effects());

      if (MouseL.down())
      {
          // エフェクトを追加する
          effect.add<RingEffect>(Cursor::Pos());
      }

      // アクティブなエフェクトのプログラム IEffect::update() を実行する
      effect.update();
  }
}




References:

https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/flame/effects.html
https://zenn.dev/reputeless/books/siv3d-documentation
https://siv3d.github.io/ja-jp/


Yes, you can create custom effects. For the circle example though you would want to use a CircleComponent that you then add a SizeEffect or ScaleEffect to + a RemoveEffect.
But since you wanted to know about custom effects, here is a custom effect that sets the strokeWidth or a paint on a Component that is using the HasPaint mixin:
/// The strokeWidth of your paint will go from 0 to thickness.
class ColorThicknessEffect extends ComponentEffect<HasPaint> {
  ColorThicknessEffect(
    this.thickness,
    EffectController controller, {
    void Function()? onComplete,
    super.key,
  })  : assert(
          thickness >= 0,
          'Thickness should be greater than 0',
        ),
        super(controller, onComplete: onComplete);

  final double thickness;
  late double _originalThickness;

  @override
  Future<void> onMount() async {
    super.onMount();

    _originalThickness = target.paint.strokeWidth;
  }

  @override
  void apply(double progress) {
    target.paint.strokeWidth = thickness * progress;
  }

  @override
  void reset() {
    super.reset();
    target.paint.strokeWidth = _originalThickness;
  }
}


Undefined name '_originalThickness'. I forced to have the property, but another error occurred.

Just add the variable for it, I added it to the example too. Do not that it's quite rare that you have to create your own effects, you can most of the time just use a combination of the already built-it effects.

note* (typo in the last comment)

I tried using it, but there was an error.I tried using it, but there was an error: The following LateError was thrown during a scheduler callback: LateInitializationError: Field 'target' has not been initialized. / Could you also include the side that is using this class?

This class isn't used anywhere, I just wrote up pseudo:ish code example to show how you could implement your own effect. There is a whole section of effects on https://examples.flame-engine.org though.
